# render hook_theme()

Tags: 7, theming

I'm developing a module which should display a tpl.php file. Check this code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function cookiedo_theme() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'cookiedo');
  return array(
    'cookiedo_info' => array(
      'template' => '/theme/cookiedo.theme',
      'path' => $path,
    ),
  );
}
```

There are no mistakes right? So i'd like to output/render cookiedo.theme.tpl.php, how should I do this?

this is all I can come up with.. :

```
  function cookiedo_preprocess_page() {

    cookiedo_theme('cookiedo_info'); 

}
```

I can possibly display this in a block/region, but I prefer to display the cookie.theme.tpl.php on all pages without the use of a block. The output should take place inside the .module file, I don't want the need to put extra code in the main template file.

I hope you understand my problem and question.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not quite how `hook_theme()` works...Drupal's theme registry will pick up the themes you define in that function, and to call them you use the central [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7) function.

You also need one of `render element` or `variables` in there (even if you're not passing any). The path defaults to the module that the hook is defined in so there's no need to specify. So your `hook_theme()` should look like this:

```
function cookiedo_theme() {
  return array(
    'cookiedo_info' => array(
      'template' => '/theme/cookiedo.theme',
      'variables' => array()
    ),
  );
}
```

And in your preprocess function you would call that theme like so:

```
$output = theme('cookiedo_info');
```

Remember to clear the caches once you make the change to the theme function or it won't get picked up by the registry.

Comment: thanks for your answer clive, I had to add print $output; to the preprocess function in order to make it work, is this the correct way?

Comment: You would normally use something like `$vars['output'] = $output;` in the preprocess function and then `print $output;` in page.tpl.php